Not able to create a free trial instance in dynamics 365 CRM
I am not able to create a free trial instance of dynamics 365 sales. And even though half of the process it is asking for payment method which was not there earlier.
I want to create a free trial instance for dynamics 365 sales. Need help, let me if it is possible to do so or not.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Yes, I recently created trial account and it ask for the card detail. You have to enter it and it will deduct Rs.2 for confirmation.
